# Passing JS Dates() to PHP subtracts 18 hours

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

I want to select MySQLi records between a startdate and enddate so I have a JS script that allows me to enter dates (using HTML datebox type inputs) which I pass to a PHP script using JQuery's $.post method. My JS code is:

```
startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fromDate").value);
startDate = new Date(startDate.getUTCFullYear(),startDate.getUTCMonth(), startDate.getUTCDate(), startDate.getUTCHours(), startDate.getUTCMinutes(), startDate.getUTCSeconds()); 
endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("toDate").value);
endDate = new Date(endDate.getUTCFullYear(), endDate.getUTCMonth(), endDate.getUTCDate(), endDate.getUTCHours(), endDate.getUTCMinutes(), endDate.getUTCSeconds()); 
$.post("DBQuery.php", {
    startdate: startDate,
    enddate: endDate,
},
function (output) {
var result = JSON.parse(output);
    $('#PHPStartDate').html(result.startdate).show();
    $('#PHPEndDate').html(result.enddate).show();
});
```

My PHP code is:

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST["startdate"]));
$enddate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST["enddate"]));
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbase");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM Hits WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
$visitors = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT session FROM Hits WHERE timestamp BETWEEN   '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
$sessions = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT country FROM Hits WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
$countries = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT city FROM Hits WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
$cities = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
$output = json_encode(array("visitors"=>$visitors,"sessions"=>$sessions,"countries"=>$countries,"cities"=>$cities,"startdate"=>$startdate,"enddate"=>$enddate));
echo $output;
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

However the dates returned by PHP are 18 hours behind the dates which JS passed to PHP - very weird! My browser and MAMP server are on  the same machine (my iMac) and I live in Thailand (UTC + 7 hours).

Here's a screen shot of what is displayed in HTML using the following code:

```
<div id="reportTitle">
            Report of site activity from
            <span id="startTime"></span>on<span id="startDate"></span>to
            <span id="endTime"></span>on<span id="endDate"></span><br>
            for<span id="showVisitors"></span>
            <span id="showCities"></span>
            <span id="showCountries"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="reportBody">
            <div>
                <span><h3>From</h3></span><span id="PHPStartDate"></span>
                <span><h3>to</h3></span><span id="PHPEndDate"></span>
```

The first set of dates displayed at the top of the screenshot are simply the JS `startdate` and `enddate`variables and the lower set of dates are those returned by the PHP variables `$startdate` and `$enddate` which ought not to have changed (but in fact are 18 hours earlier!). 
[Screenshot of JS and PHP dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip8lU.png)
I suspect the problem is to do with timezones but given that Thailand is UTC+7 it's hard to work out where the 18 hour time difference is coming from.

Comment: You should just use the Server for time, unless you want the Client to be able to alter it. Of course, either way you should use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: I've tried inserting `date_default_timezone_set ('UTC');` into my PHP script but it makes no difference. I do need the client to be able to choose the dates because the user needs to be able to specify these as search criteria for a report.